# Route with empty path and helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to implement a "à la github" url like "github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources".

I achieved my goal with this code :

```
 resources :users, :path => '', only: [] do
   resources :projects, :path => '', only: [:show]
 end
```

But now, I can't find a way to redirect properly to this route.

When I run a `rake routes` in the console, all I have is

```
GET      /:user_id/:id(.:format)        projects#show
```

and no name to find a helper method like my old `users_project_path`.

Have I miss something ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently did something similar, try the following

```
scope '/:user_id', as: :user do
  resources :projects, path: '', only: [:show]
end
```

Running `rake routes` should then give you

```
user_project GET    /:user_id/:id(.:format)        projects#show
```

and this will give you the proper `user_project_path(:user_id, :id)` route helper.

Answer (score 0):

You're deleting the path for this reason you can get route_path, use as to establish a route name.

```
resources :users, :path => '', only: [] do
   get :projects, "/:user_id/:id", :to => "project#show", :as => :project_user
 end
```

OR if you don't want use that you can use this code for generating path:

```
url_for([@user, @project])
```